# $_SESSION work in mozilla not work in chrome

Tags: php, sql, google-chrome, mozilla, isset

Orders page ready, everything is nicely saved to the database (MSQL) assuming that the order ID assigns from the finger in input. I wanted to add a code that will download the last ID from the database and increment them by 1 saving the result to the session. I test everything in two browsers MOZILLA and CHROME. By entering the add-order page, the new order ID is automatically assigned, adds new products to the form using input POST method and everything works BUT only in Mozilla. Chrome behaves as if it were creating a new session every time, i.e. no matter if the session exists or does not  it's giving a new value. Like  !ISSET did not work. It simply performs the entire code without considering whether the session exists or not. In the whole "system" I have used the solution! Here is such a surprise. Take a look what can be wrong or what can be solved better / different?

P.S, anticipating questions id_zam in sql is not autoincrement because autoincrement has been used for another option in this table and so it has to stay.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ID-zam']) OR ($_SESSION['ID-zam']==FALSE)){
        $pol = $polaczenie-> query( "SELECT MAX( id_zam )AS max FROM `orders`" );
        $row =  $pol->fetch_array();
        $order = $row['max'];
        $_SESSION['ID-zam']=$order+1;
        $order2=$_SESSION['ID-zam'];

        }else{$order2=$_SESSION['ID-zam'];}
```

Comment: _“Chrome behaves as if it were creating a new session every time”_ - well perhaps a new session _is_ created every time, because the session id does not get passed back correctly with the next request ...? So _check_ whether the session itself works correctly, by checking what the current session id is before and after.

Comment: Why use the following conditional check at all? `$_SESSION['ID-zam']==FALSE`.

Comment: Are you using `session_start()`? Are cookies enabled in your browser?  Can you store and retrieve any test value in $_SESSION?  Or rather; first test and confirm sessions are working.

Comment: You could still end up with the same order number between different clients with that code.

Comment: misorude after else var_dump($_SESSION['ID-zam']); in mozilla is giving right value. And in mozilla and other browser  everything is fine.
Progrock - I added this "$_SESSION['ID-zam']==FALSE"  after 10h serching and testing different solutions, session_start is on the top of page. Other sesions in this page in different ids works fine only this one !isset is not working. I knowe that different clients can have the same number but there will be onlu one user -> me because its closed system.

Comment: have you dumped the complete session? See if there other changes as well.

Comment: I have some progress, in index.php i had unset for this session, when i delete this, page orders started to work fine. But i haven't got any links or forwarding to index.php when i do $_POST so why unseting in index.php works? 
it code to $_POST

Comment: @PrzemysławKacprzyk, be careful, sometimes pages can be pre-fetched without your knowledge, especially in Chrome.  The new tab page for example holds a list of links, I wouldn't be surprised if a link to index.php was listed there.  I'd probably suggest only clearing the existing session at login.

Comment: @ Progrock  Thanks for your time! Now it's like you said session is unseting only when user want it(if click "delete order")  i think this topic i close :) Now i need to read more about arrays in sessions. Have a nice day!